# Go Generics - Hold a map of generic interfaces

Tags: go, generics

I'm refactoring some of my code now that Go 1.18 is out with the new Generics feature.
I've created a generic interface i.e

```golang
type IExample[T any] interface{
    ExampleFunc(ex T) T
}
```

Somewhere in my code, I want to store several implementations of this interface in a map and use them generically in my code.

```golang
mapping := map[string]IExample{
        // .......
}
```

But the go compiler throws this error `cannot use generic type types.SettingsAdapter[T any] without instantiation`

So, I tried adding `any` to the generic type

```golang
mapping := map[string]IExample[any]{
        // .......
}
```

Which resulted in the following error

```
IExample[any] does not implement IExampleImpl[ExampleT]
```

At this point, I feel that there's something I'm missing while implementing the code, or that I'm just using this feature in a way that it wasn't meant to be used.

Thanks :)

Comment: `any` is the same as `interface{}`, i.e. the empty interface. When you instantiate a `IExample` with `any`, the only values you can then assign to it are **exactly** those that implement `IExample[any]`, i.e. have method `ExampleFunc(ex any) any`

Comment: cont: different instances of `IExample[T]` are different types altogether. If you want to declare *a single variable* that can hold arbitrary instances of `IExample[T]` you are back to `map[string]any`

Comment: What are `IExampleImp` and `ExampleT`? They're declared nowhere in your code. Also, the `I` prefix in interface name is not welcome in Go :)